# React/HTML Best practices for table element vs divs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[Bill Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfplC.png)

This would be my item component which gets instantiated through my bill component

```
export default function Item (props) {

    return (
      <div className="item">
            <span>{props.itemName}</span>
            <span>$ {(props.price * props.quantity).toFixed(2)}</span>
            <button className='qtyminus' field='quantity' 
    onClick={() => {props.decrementFunction(props.itemName, props.price)}}
    ><span>-</span>
    </button> 
    <button className='qtyplus' field='quantity' 
    onClick={() => {props.incrementFunction(props.itemName, props.price)}}
    ><span>+</span></button>  
    <button className='deleteItem'
    onClick={()=> {props.deleteItemFunction(props.itemName, props.price)}} 
    ><span>x</span>
    </button>
    {/* <div>{props.quantity}</div> */}
      </div>
    )
}
```

and here's basically the category bar above the bill container div which
lists the categories of each item

```
<div className="bill-category">
<div>Item</div>
<div>Price</div>
<div>Quantity</div>
</div>
```

As I'm working through finishing this component, I'm having quite some trouble adjusting the CSS category alignments with the item names, price and buttons that come along with it. Would it be better practice to completely refactor my code to use table/rows/cols tags in this case? Please let me know your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write semantic markup
2. Apply CSS to make it look the way you want

You appear to have tabular data. Use a table.

Answer (score 0):

From a personal experience, you may gain some performance if you use DIV instead of TABLE in case you have really huge data and you want to dynamically add or remove columns.
But in long term I still prefer table since it is more semantically correct, easily accessible out of the box and leads to less issues if printed or exported.

If you look at the rendering of the big component vendors who provide datatable/grids you would see some are using tables and some divs, both approaches scale and are usable in big projects so it would be hard to tell what is best or if it really matter for a simple pages.